# React Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

First, I want to provide a link to sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/oq36pl4j49

I am learning react+redux and trying to build a simple quiz prototype.

My main idea is:

- keep all questions in redux store and also update them there.
- `quizengine.currentQuestion` is telling render which question to
  render, so I am just dispatching action which is changing `quizengine.currentQuestion` and render deal the rest
- Back and Next buttons are navigation and they belong to question. The reason is sometimes I need to hide them for example if there is a different type of question like multiple than clicking to answer triggering `goToNext` so I can hide Next or the first question don't have Back button.

Everything is working for now but When I am pressing Back or Next I have an issue in the console:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition 
(such as within `render` or another component's constructor).
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; 
constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern,
but can be moved to `componentWillMount`
```

I was trying to change

```
<button className="btn prev" onClick={goToPrev}>Back</button>
<button className="btn next" onClick={goToNext}>Next</button>
```

to that:

```
<button className="btn prev" onClick={() => {goToPrev()}}>Back</button>
<button className="btn next" onClick={() => {goToNext()}}>Next</button>
```

But it's still not helping.

Am I going it in the right direction??

Is that small App makes sense??

That's how my store look like:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to show the component where `goToPrev` is called. Sounds like you are updating state in multiple places

Comment: YES!! that was the issue thanks, I just realized that I had code in 'PlusMinusControll'  so it was trigerring update itself.

Answer (score 0):

add a function like this:

```
goToPrev = () => {
    this.context.router.goBack();
}
```

and in render() use this:

```
<button className="btn prev" onClick={ this.goToPrev }>Back</button>
```